# Kmail: Increase horizontal spacing in message list

Tags: kubuntu, customization, kmail

I want to increase the horizontal spacing in the message list in Kmail. I find that the spacing is a bit too close to each other, and would like more space between the emails in the message list.

I have attached a photo which is unfortunately not very clear as I had to blur out information, so had to mark the current spacing with red lines to show what I am looking for.I need to increase the space between the red lines (which is the divider)so my message list can be clearer.

I have done this in the past with Thunderbird, where I changed the userChrome.css file to increase the spacing and now I would like to do the same with KMail.

If you can help me to increase the message list horizontal space (redlines) then that would be great.

With Thunderbird (in the past) I have edited the userChrome.css file to the following (second image)

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that KMAIL have a option for this:

Go to View> Message List > Theme > Configure

Click on clone the theme you want and rename theme.

Click on Advance tab and drop drag horizontal line spacing below the sender/ subject list to increase spacing.

Also ensure that you have the setting to "show message list on right" in the main Kmail Configuration settings if you like the Outlook style.